# Can't Access elmah.axd When Running ASP.net MVC on Apache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, mono, elmah

I'm using MVC2, mono 2.10.5, mod-mono-server4.

ELMAH is configured as per [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs), but I am using the XML file logger.

When trying to access /elmah.axd locally I get the following message in error log (indicating that the logging capabilities for ELMAH are working):

> The controller for path '/elmah.axd' was not found or does not implement IController.

The following is still present in Global.asax's RegisterRoutes method as well:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute ("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

It seems like adding the handlers for ELMAH is not working with apache - it is working on a windows 7 desktop with cassini, haven't tried with IIS.

I can post more details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but I've followed the directions [here](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/03/integrating-elmah-to-aspnet-mvc-in.html) to display ELMAH information in a more MVC-friendly way (this makes it easier to allow remote access as well).  I'm running into another mono-specific error now, but I will post that as a new question.